# Read complete header of an email

Tags: php, imap

I want to read complete header of an email. I am using IMAP for this but I am unable to get body(content) part received in header. Is it possible to get this.

```
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<html>
<head>
```

Comment: **Meet [`IMAP4`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501).** You'll learn all that is possible.

Comment: Sir is there any document which provide few examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If you want to fetch all, you need to fetch
```

- The headers imap_fetchheader.
- Obtain the number of bodies the message has imap_fetchstructure.
- Each mine-headers a body has imap_fetchmime.
- Each body it has imap_fetchbody.

  Proceed like below -:
   $hang =imap_fetchheader($loginToInbox,$email);
   $hang .="\n".imap_body($loginToInbox, $email);
  And then directly use INSERT command to make its entry in DB.

Answer (score 1):

`UID FETCH {$MessageID} (FLAGS BODY.PEEK[])` will fetch but not mark as read. This is wisdom from a protocol implementation of mine I did in C++.

In `PHP` I think you need to test `imap_fetchbody()` and the other `imap_fetch*()` functions. Or use [`imap_fetchstructure()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) which fetches all parts so you can handle them as you wish.

**PS**: *There are examples on the PHP.net function pages. Look at the bottom, user contributions mainly.*

Comment: I want to hold full header in DB below is header part which i want to get:

Comment: @abhinavdixit I don't understand what you want. Test all those functions and see which produces desired output.

Comment: sir i had just raised one new question which might give complete idea of what i am trying to do.

Comment: How to store complete header of an email in DB please search quetion with subject line.